# Java Graphics Drawing Custom Circular

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, spiral

I want to draw a shape at center that starts from the center of the panel and keeps expanding out in circular shape like in the picture link below :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lnxi1be8uogn2zx/20140320_124537.jpg

but i am having difficulty with the center shape , its like it doesnt show up at all on the panel. Here is the class i wrote for the shapes

```
package graphics.test;


import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    //top right corner
    g.drawLine(0, 0, width/4, height/6);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, width/4, height/4);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, width/4, height/3);
    //top left corner
    g.drawLine(width, 0, width - width/4, height/6);
    g.drawLine(width, 0, width - width/4, height/4);
    g.drawLine(width, 0, width - width/4, height/3);
    //bottom left corner
    g.drawLine(width, height, width - width/3, height - height/6);
    g.drawLine(width, height, width - width/4, height - height/4);
    g.drawLine(width, height, width - width/4, height - height/3);
    //bottom right corner
    g.drawLine(0, height, width/3, height - height/6);
    g.drawLine(0, height, width/4, height - height/4);
    g.drawLine(0, height, width/4, height - height/3);
    //center

    for (int i = width/2; i < width/3; i--)
    {
        for (int j = height/2; j < height/3; j--)
        {
            g.drawLine(i,j,i,j);
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like an Archimedean Spiral ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral )

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SpiralDrawPanelTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(new SpiralDrawPanel(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setSize(800, 800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class SpiralDrawPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;

        AffineTransform at = 
            AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(
                getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);

        BasicStroke stroke =
            new BasicStroke(1.0f,
                BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER,
                10.0f, new float[]{10.0f}, 0.0f);
        g.setStroke(stroke);
        Shape shape = 
            at.createTransformedShape(
                createArchimedeanSpiral(Math.PI*10, 10, 250));
        g.draw(shape);

    }

    private static Shape createArchimedeanSpiral(
        double totalAngleRad, double alpha, int steps)
    {
        Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        double angleDeltaRad = totalAngleRad / steps;
        for (int i=0; i<=steps; i++)
        {
            double angleRad = i * angleDeltaRad;
            double x = Math.sin(angleRad) * alpha * angleRad;
            double y = Math.cos(angleRad) * alpha * angleRad;
            path.lineTo(x, y);
        }
        return path;

    }
}
```

---

EDIT for the comment.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SpiralDrawPanelTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(new SpiralDrawPanel(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setSize(800, 800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class SpiralDrawPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        paintArchimedeanSpiral(g, getWidth()/2,  getHeight()/2, Math.PI * 10, 10, 250);
    }

    private static void paintArchimedeanSpiral(
        Graphics g, 
        double centerX, double centerY,
        double totalAngleRad, double alpha, int steps)
    {
        Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        double angleDeltaRad = totalAngleRad / steps;
        for (int i=0; i<=steps; i+=2)
        {
            double angleRad0 = i * angleDeltaRad;
            double angleRad1 = i * angleDeltaRad + angleDeltaRad;
            double x0 = centerX + Math.sin(angleRad0) * alpha * angleRad0;
            double y0 = centerY + Math.cos(angleRad0) * alpha * angleRad0;
            double x1 = centerX + Math.sin(angleRad1) * alpha * angleRad1;
            double y1 = centerY + Math.cos(angleRad1) * alpha * angleRad1;
            g.drawLine((int)x0, (int)y0, (int)x1, (int)y1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ty for the quick answer i was able to fix my codes and add that to it but I kinda wanted it just using JFrame JPanel and Graphics library , it it possible to do it using those 3 only?

Comment: @Rage91 Of course this is possible. It's somewhat stupid, and you should have mentioned it right from the beginning ("Walking on water and developing software to specification are easy as long as both are frozen"), but however, who cares, I added an EDIT. It this is not what you want, you should create a new question, because the original one obviously was lacking sufficient specification.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that and yeah this one is what i wanted thank you for the answers :D